# Swift Codable with Custom JSONDecoder with Custom dateDecodingStrategy failing when Device is not using 24 hours format

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable

I am getting dates from server in below format

```
"endTime": "2022-12-12T16:20:00.000Z"
```

I am using Codable to parse json to Objects. I am using a custom decoder shown below

```swift
internal func getDecoder() -> JSONDecoder {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
    return decoder
}
```

It works perfectly when device time format is set as 24 Hours format. But it returns null if device time is not set as 24 hours format. Is there any other property I have to set?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom JSONDecoder with a custom dateDecodingStrategy in Swift and you encounter issues with decoding dates when the device's time format is not set to 24-hour format, there are a few potential solutions.

One solution is to use the ISO8601DateFormatter class to parse the date string and convert it to a Date object. This class is designed to handle the different date and time formats defined in the ISO 8601 standard, so it is well-suited to handling the potential variations that can occur in date strings. Here is an example:

let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()

// Set the timeZone property to the local time zone
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current

// Parse the date string using the ISO8601DateFormatter
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2022-12-12T12:00:00")

Another solution is to use the DateFormatter class and explicitly set its dateFormat property to match the format of the date string you are trying to decode. This allows you to specify the exact format of the date string and ensures that the DateFormatter will be able to parse it correctly. Here is an example:

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

// Set the dateFormat property to match the format of the date string
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

// Set the timeZone property to the local time zone
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current

// Parse the date string using the DateFormatter
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2022-12-12T12:00:00")

Once you have parsed the date string into a Date object, you can use this object when decoding the JSON data using your custom JSONDecoder and dateDecodingStrategy. This should allow you to properly decode the dates in the JSON data, regardless of the device's time format.

Note that in both of these examples, it is important to set the timeZone property of the DateFormatter or ISO8601DateFormatter to the local time zone. This ensures that the parsed Date objects will be correctly adjusted for the device's time zone, which is important for ensuring that the dates are decoded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you create `DateFormatter` without setting `locale` to `"en_US_POSIX"`. By default it uses the current locale which respects the user settings, which cases an issue if he disables the "Settings > General > Date & Time > 24-Hour Time".

As mentioned you can also use `ISO8601DateFormatter` that already should behave as expected or the newer API `Date.ISO8601FormatStyle`.